# @Published Attributed Strings Not Working

Tags: string, swiftui

Attributed Strings don't seem to retain their attributes when created in the ViewModel and passed to a SwiftUI View.  Is there a way to make @Published strings with bold/italics/etc in a ViewModel that retain their attributes in the View?

The following correctly applies bold styling

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       Text( "**This** should be bold")
   }
}
```

However, when using a ViewModel it produces: `**This** should be bold`

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var attributedString = "**This** should be bold"
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
       Text(viewModel.attributedString)
   }
}
```

I've also tried setting the type as AttributedString, however that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AttributedString(markdown: )` but as it throws, you have to use it e.g.in the init.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var attributedString: AttributedString
    
    init() {
        self.attributedString = ""
        try? attributedString = AttributedString(markdown: "**This** should be bold")
    }
}
```